# Defined negation in intuitionistic linear logic

Tags: logic, intuitionistic-logic, nonclassical-logic, linear-logic

Is it possible to define a negation in intuitionistic linear logic, the way one does in intuitionistic logic, i.e. $A^{\bot} \equiv A \multimap \mathbf{0}$ (or, as it would be written in intuitionistic logic, $\neg A \equiv A \to \bot$)?

While I can prove, e.g. the theorem...
$$A^{\bot\bot}\otimes B^{\bot\bot}\vdash(A\otimes B)^{\bot\bot}$$

...I cannot prove...
$$(A\otimes B)^{\bot\bot}\vdash A^{\bot\bot}\otimes B^{\bot\bot}$$

...without copying the assumption $(A\otimes B)^{\bot\bot}$ to both subproofs $A^{\bot\bot}$ and $B^{\bot\bot}$. Even though I end up only using the $A$ and $B$ parts once, I still have to copy the assumption.

---

Edit: For completeness' sake, the system I'm using is the one introduced in [Philip Wadler's, *A Taste of Linear Logic*](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/lineartaste/lineartaste-revised.pdf).

---

Edit: Just to make sure, I checked, and $(A\otimes B)^{\bot\bot}\equiv A^{\bot\bot}\otimes B^{\bot\bot}$ is a theorem of linear logic under the axiomatisation on the [Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-linear/#SeqCal) (as it should be).

---

Edit: [Sequent Calculi for Intuitionistic Linear Logic with Strong Negation](http://jigpal.oxfordjournals.org/content/10/6/653.short) by Norihiro Kamide seems to be a relevant publication.

Comment: $\multimap$? I have not seen this befor. What does it do?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Can't say exactly, but it stands for implication in a relevant logic (where for example $A \to (B \to A)$ is not valid)

Comment: It stands (in this case) for implication in linear logic. The idea is that you have to use every argument of the implication *exactly* once, meaning that the theorem mentioned by Stefan isn't valid, and neither is $A \to (A\wedge A)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a late answer, but you made some good observations. Negation *can* be defined in intuitionistic linear logic, but it doesn't satisfy all of the properties of either classical linear negation or intuitionistic non-linear negation – that doesn't mean it's a bad definition! The definition you gave ($\neg A := A \multimap 0$) is fine, but an even better one is $$\neg A := A \multimap p$$
where $p$ is a fixed, atomic formula not appearing in $A$. (The main difference between these two definitions is that your definition validates [ex falso quod libet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion) (also called the [principle of explosion](https://xkcd.com/704/))
$A \otimes \neg A \vdash B$
for generic formulas $B$, while the other definition doesn't.)
In any case, with either definition, one can prove double-negation introduction
$$
A \vdash \neg\neg A
$$
but not double-negation elimination (even though it is valid classically), and likewise one can prove the distributivity law
$$
\neg \neg A \otimes \neg\neg B \vdash \neg\neg(A \otimes B)
$$
but not the reverse entailment (even though it is valid intuitionistically).
(There are actually two distinct, canonical ways of proving $\neg \neg A \otimes \neg\neg B \vdash \neg\neg(A \otimes B)$. Can you spot them?)

The fragment of intuitionistic linear logic consisting of *just* tensor ($\otimes$) and negation ($\neg$) has a surprisingly rich structure – Paul-André Melliès calls this fragment "[tensorial logic](https://www.irif.fr/~mellies/tensorial-logic.html)" and has written a lot about it (e.g., see his paper with Nicolas Tabareau, [Resource modalities in tensor logic](https://www.irif.fr/~mellies//papers/resource-modalities-apal.pdf)). In particular, there is a good motivation for studying such a weak form of negation that comes from the theory of programming languages: $\neg A$ is precisely the type of *linear continuations*.

Comment: I'm not sure how your definition of $\neg$ would apply in the case $\neg\neg A$. I can get to $\neg(A\multimap p)$ easily, but to unfold the outer negation it looks like I would need to deviate _either_ from your specification that $p$ is "fixed" or from the specification that it doesn't appear in the formula to be negated...